# How do you input something to python

Tags: python, macos

sorry for such a noob question but how exactly do you input something to python. I am not talking about the function but rather what is the physical button on the keyboard do you press to finish your input? For example, the code (random found):

```
 value = input("Please enter a string:\n")
 
print(f'You entered {value} and its type is {type(value)}'
```

After you type in the string, what button do you press? I am using the OSX IDLE key-binding and the Return key just end the program.

Comment: When you press return, it should finish executing the program, which includes printing the given message, and then terminate. Are you sure it's not doing that? If the window auto-closes on termination, then you'll need to change your settings to fix that, as that's an OS problem, not a Python one.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yup, it is definitely not doing that. I tried Hello, then press Return, and the whole thing just ended, with a new indent for a new code, but the window doesn't close.

Comment: I just noticed you are missing a parenthesis on the second line of your code. Just add a `)` at the end.

Comment: @Merp That's just me hastily copied it wrong. The code I have on my screen right now includes it, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will print : `Please enter a string:`.

Then you just type in whatever, 'hello' for example and hit enter.

And it will output: `You entered hello and its type is <class 'str'>`

Then, like @Silvio said, it will immediately close, but that is easily fixed with another `input()` statement at the end of you code.

Comment: I tried that but it did nothing, and it indents for a new code instead.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Could you show an example of a run?

Comment: Ok here it the code again: ```>>> value = input("Please enter a string:\n")
 
print(f'You entered {value} and its type is {type(value)}')```. Its output: ```Please enter a string:``` What I typed in: ```Hello```. Pressed enter. What I got, in total: ```Please enter a string:
Hello
>>> ``` So basically it just ended abruptly after pressing Enter.

Comment: Are you running it in the command prompt?

Comment: I am not sure what that means. However, I am using IDLE that came packaged with my downloaded Python, if it helps.

Comment: Are you running a saved file in IDLE or do you have to re enter everything each time with the `>>>`things?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Ok, try pasting you're code in notepad and saving as (blank).py and double click it.

Comment: Haha, now pressing Return doesn't even run the first line.

Comment: Ok, I might have to give up IDLE and look at another IDE instead. Thank you very much, still.

Comment: Np. Sorry we couldn't get it fixed. Could i see your code one last time?

Comment: This is just a test run so there is nothing more to it. But my full screen is just this: ```>>> value = input("Please enter a string:\n")
 
print(f'You entered {value} and its type is {type(value)}')
Please enter a string:
Hello
>>> ``` One possibility is that for whatever reason, IDLE is simply not reading print() properly and is refusing to do so. So the code technically ran fine, just 0 output

Comment: I even ran it in IDLE, since that's where those `>>>` came from, and it worked for me.

Comment: Try hitting the windows button, type in `cmd` and hit enter. Once there just type `python` or `py` maybe and then put in the rest of your code and try that.

Comment: I am using Macbook.

Comment: Ok, then go to this [link](https://code.sololearn.com/python) and type your code in and run.

Comment: Yup, that link you just sent me works. So must be due to my mac vs IDLE.

Comment: Glad I could help.